# Nopcommerce PerRequestCacheManager vs MemoryCacheManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, nopcommerce

I am working on NopCommerce 2.40 . I want to set Cache on home page using CacheManager.

```
    var cacheModel = _cacheManager.Get(cacheKey, () =>
                {
                    var model = new HomePageProductsModel()
                     {
                    ....
                    ....

                     }
                  return model;
                });
```

When I debug this code. It hits Get method in MemoryCacheManager. Now at admin side when I want to remove this cache by Key when I update any product. Remove method called below hits Remove of PerRequestCacheManager.

```
 _cacheManager.Remove(string.Format("product.hometemplate-{0}-{1}", storeid, true));
```

So this cache on home page is not removed. Is there any solution to it

Answer (score 4):

Some controllers in the Nop.Web project use MemoryCacheManager. These controllers with static cache (MemoryCacheManager) are defined in the \Nop.Web\Infrastructure\DependencyRegistrar.cs file. In this file we define which one of ICacheManager implementations should be injected.

But I would recommend you to use the same approach which is used in nopCommerce. Use events. Subscribe to product insert/delete/update events in the \Nop.Web\Infrastructure\Cache\ModelCacheEventConsumer.cs file and reset cache there. Just see how it's already done there.

Comment: thanks @and.maz. I have changed DependencyRegistrar for ImportManager service with this statement builder.RegisterType<ImportManager>().As<IImportManager>()
            .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager> ("nop_cache_static")).InstancePerHttpRequest(); as I am writing method to clear cache in ImportManager   would that be ok?

Comment: Current MemoryCache is set for 60 minutes , can i have it forever until i remove it manually, ofcourse i am going to remove it everyday.